# Displaying a view on top of Tab Bar instead of within

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a few tab bar applications that also use navigation controllers within the tab bar.  I would like to be able to present a view when a cell in the table view is clicked, but have it not be IN the tab bar controller.  This would be similar to the Twitter app when a link is clicked from within a Tweet.  This way, the view for that link can be rotated, while everything else in the tab bar won't rotate.  Here is how my code is setup now:

```
 self.webViewController = [[[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:_webViewController animated:YES];
```

I just want the view to cover up the tab bar, and therefore, let it rotate without needing to allow everything in tab bar to also rotate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present a view controller above everything else on screen then I recommend you present it modally. Here's an example:

```
self.webViewController = [[[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
[self presentViewController:self.webViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, presenting it modally still requires that every view in the tab bar also return YES to - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

Comment: No it doesn't.  Subclass UITabBarController (create your own custom class) and then override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to suit how you want all the VC's managed by the TabBar Controller to act.  Override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in any view you want to be different from that "default" implementation.